# installation problem ubuntu / kubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu, 23.10

I have a computer with an empty ssd and an asrock motherboard (z790m-itx) and onboard intel graphics.

I plug in a working bootable ubuntu 23.10 usb medium. Always after the first time the ubuntu logo is shown (at the very beginning of the installation process), the computer powers off and tries to reboot.

I do the same with a kubuntu 23.10 usb medium, and installation works flawlessly.

I try again with ubuntu 23.10, select the usb medium in the boot order, and it powers off again.

Same experience after switching fastboot and secure boot from off to on and back again.
The boot parameter `nomodeset` changes nothing.

What could it be that makes the difference here?